# Creating a restful API using PHP as server and jQuery as client

Tags: php, jquery, api

I'm trying to create a Javascript client API service which calls the API of my site. This will be cross domain and i'm aware of the problems this causes. However, I need the user to send through some user credentials (whether that be their username and password *encoded obviously* or an API key + secret) so that I can return user specific details.

I initially looked at using the `jsonp` datatype however this doesnt allow you to set any custom headers so ruled this out.

I've been searching the web for a while and been unable to find a secure way of doing this cross domain, has anyone had any success with this and can give me some advice?

UPDATE:

I've tried this following code as suggested by lu1s, however I get an alert of 'boo' as stated n the error function..

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.dotsandboxes.co.cc/__tests/cors.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { alert('hello!'); },
    error: function() { alert('boo!'); },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('securityCode', 'Foo');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('passkey', 'Bar');
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: If you can't use JSON with a callback (jsonp) then you might only have a couple other options like flash or silverlight. However, can't you work around the header problem by embedding the headers inside the request/response?

Comment: I'd ideally would like to use this on cell phones so flash / silverlight is out the question. I'd like to just use JavaScript as a client

Comment: @Xeoncross no i cant embed this in the request / response as browsers stop this due to cross domain security issues

Comment: You must not be doing it right. Cross-domain requests are possible if the request takes the form of loading a resource and the resource invokes a callback. So as long as your PHP API returns the JSON results with a callback all should be good.

Comment: Matt, try removing the beforeSend function. The server side is not handling xhr authentication so it may not be returning the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can. Try adding the `Allow-Access-Control-Origin: *` to your HTTP response headers, as well as the correct content-type.

Try with a simple PHP script like this:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-type: text/json');
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'data'=>'foobar'));
?>
```

Check this site to read more info about cross-origin: http://enable-cors.org/

About the authentication, it's NOT recommended to send usernames or passwords, even if they're encrypted. As you stated, it's better to pass a token in the URL. Best if following standards like http://oauth.net/2/ .

Comment: I'd ideally like to use oauth however it appears using javascript as a client cross domain is a no go zone as stated here: http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/README.txt

Comment: also i've tried adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` however this doesnt appear to make any difference

Comment: Matt, it works for me. Try performing a `$.getJSON` to http://www.dotsandboxes.co.cc/__tests/cors.php (don't forget the www)

Comment: Matt, did you try with `dataType: "jsonp"` ? Oh and by the way, you don't need to send any xhr parameters. It's easier, try with `$.getJSON("http://www.dotsandboxes.co.cc/__tests/cors.php", function(response){ alert(response.data); });`

Comment: Hi Lu1s, I need to send XHR params as it is these I will be using to send authentication details in my client API call, so to be able to replicate exactly what i will be seeing when i get this working, i need to use the same code as if it was calling my api service

Comment: Matt. I understand that, but first things first. In this case, the request you're performing to my site will only handle raw get requests with no parameters. You can however authenticate with a token passed as GET param. As I understand, XHR will get you trouble for cross-domain.